# How to use TransferUtility with Cognito user / Identity pools in Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, incognito-mode, awss3transferutility

I need to upload one file in Android to an s3 bucket.
We want to authenticate the upload with Cognito User pools.

The standard way to do this would be to use the Storage API from the Amazon Amplify SDK.

Problem is that I need to report upload progress for the upload, and Amplify Storage does not allow you to set a listener to observe Progress in Android.

That takes me to the need of using `TransferUtility`.

How I am supposed to authenticate the upload operation using Cognito with TransferUtility?

At the moment I'm doing:

```
            val credentials = CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                context,
                "eu-west-1:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
                Regions.US_WEST_1)

            val s3Client = AmazonS3Client(credentials, Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_1))

            val transferUtility = TransferUtility.builder()
                .context(context)
                .s3Client(s3Client)
                .build()
```

But I'm getting a 403:

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: XXXXXXXXXXX), S3 Extended Request ID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx=
```

I'm really struggling to get any documentation for this, as it seems the `Storage` API is now preferred over `TransferUtility`, and everything to do with Cognito user pools or user identities is done with Amplitude Storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found some documentation do to this.
Basically, you use `AWSMobileClient` as the implementation for the `AWSConfiguration` with building the `TransferUtility`

```
        TransferUtility transferUtility =
            TransferUtility.builder()
                .context(getApplicationContext())
                .awsConfiguration(AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getConfiguration())
                .s3Client(new AmazonS3Client(AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getCredentialsProvider()))
                .build();

        TransferObserver uploadObserver =
            transferUtility.upload(
                "s3Folder/s3Key.txt",
                new File("/path/to/file/localFile.txt"));
```

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-mobile-developer-guide/blob/master/doc_source/how-to-transfer-files-with-transfer-utility.rst

Also, there are two other caveats I had to figure out to make this work without receiving HTTP 403:

1. Add required information to `awsconfiguration.json`

```
{
  "IdentityManager": {
    "Default": {}
  },
  "CognitoUserPool": {
    "Default": {
      "PoolId": "region_XXXXXXX",
      "AppClientId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "Region": "XXXXX"
    }
  },
  "CredentialsProvider": {
    "CognitoIdentity": {
      "Default": {
        "PoolId": "XXXXX:XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "Region": "XXXXXX"
      }
    }
  },
  "S3TransferUtility": {
    "Default": {
      "Bucket": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-data-bucket",
      "Region": "XXXXXX"
    }
  }
}
```

Note that `CredentialsProvider.CognitoIdentity.Default.PoolId` is not the same as 
`CognitoUserPool.Default.PoolId`!

2. Prepend the "private"/"public" prefix to the `key` when performing the upload if required, depending on the server-side configuration.